# Односвязный список и вставка элементов

Tags: c++

Тут реализованный односвязный список. Есть добавление элементов в конец и вставка элементов в любое место. Вставка работает, но когда вставляешь элемент по позиции 0 программа вылетает. Как мне вставить элемент в нулевую позицию?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>

class List // класс список
{

public:

    List(); // конструктор
    ~List(); // деструктор

    void push_back(T data); // вставить в конец списка 
    int GetSize() { return Size; }
    T& operator[](const int index);
    void add(T data, int pos);

public:
    template<typename T>

    class Node // класс "Узел"
    {

    public:
        Node *pNext; // указатель на следующий элемент 
        T data; // данные

        Node(T data = T(), Node *pNext = nullptr) // по умолчанию пусто
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->pNext = pNext;
        }

    };
    void* getAt(int index);
private:

    Node<T> *head; // голова
    int Size;  // для хранения количества элементов 

};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
    Size = 0;
    head = nullptr;

}

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{

}

template<typename T>
inline void List<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    if (head == nullptr) // если голова пустая 
    {
        head = new Node<T>(data); // создаём голову 

    }
    else { // если нет

        Node<T> * current = this->head; // создаём времменая переменная с указателем на current и присваиваем ей значение заголовка
        while (current->pNext != nullptr) // поиск следующего элемента. Если сдедующий элемент не пуст 
        {
            current = current->pNext; // присваевания указателя на следующий елемент  
        }

        current->pNext = new Node<T>(data); // создаём следующий элмент 
    }
    Size++;
}

template<typename T>
inline T & List<T>::operator[](const int index) // перегрузка оператора []
{
    int counter = 0; // счётчик 

    Node<T> *current = this->head;

    while (current != nullptr) // если следующий элемент не пустой
    {
        if (counter == index) // проверка на совпадения 
        {
            return current->data; // возвращаем данные 
        }
        current = current->pNext; // указатель на следующий элемент 
        counter++; // счётчик + 1
    }
}



template<typename T>
inline void * List<T>::getAt(int index)
{
    int counter = 0;

    Node<T> *current = this->head;

    while (current != nullptr) 
    {
        if (counter++ == index)
        {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    return NULL;
};

template<typename T>
inline void List<T>::add(T data, int pos) // вставка элементов 
{

        Node<T> * prev = (Node<T> *) getAt(pos - 1), *current = new Node<T>(data), *next = (Node<T> *)getAt(pos);
        current->pNext = next;
        prev->pNext = current;
        Size++;

}

#include "List.h"

int main()
{
    int counter;
    List<int> list;
    list.push_back(5);
    list.push_back(10);
    list.push_back(15);

    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << list[a] << endl;

    cout << endl;
    list.add(21, 1);
    cout << "List" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.GetSize(); i++)
    {

        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }

    //cin >> a;
    //cout << list[a] << endl;



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужны проверки на нулевой индекс, и не забыть поменять голову списка.

```
template<typename T>
inline void List<T>::add(T data, int pos) // вставка элементов 
{
  Node<T> * prev ;
  if(pos > 0)     prev = (Node<T> *) getAt(pos - 1);

        Node<T> *current = new Node<T>(data), *next = (Node<T> *)getAt(pos);
        current->pNext = next;

        if(pos) prev->pNext = current;
        else head = current ;

        Size++; }
```

Comment: а можно нормальный код?